# Protractor tests breaking on update to new chromedriver/chrome

Tags: selenium, protractor

I have recently updated my chromedriver after chrome updated itself, to fix the usual error message for having missmatches in the two.

Thanks to this all of my protractor tests have now broken.

In brief, the issue that I am seeing (and have seen before ) is that all tests now require I first click manually on the window that is running protractor tests or else any promises seem to never resolve and the code times out by itself, no amount of waiting seems to change this.

Is there any advice people can give me for resolving this issue? I am truly baffled by this, I cant seem to find anything close to this issue by researching around and having somehow gotten rid of it once without realizing I cannot think what changed to make it go away or come back.

Comment: I had a similar issue a few weeks ago and what I did is just downgrade the versions

Comment: if you think this is chromedriver related issue, why don't you downgrade for now? pretty much possible chromedriver has a bug which will be fixed in later releases. No need to try find a workaround when you can just wait for a stable version. BTW if you do believe this is a CD bug, don't hesitate to log the issue in chromedriver bug tracking system. it's open

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm being dense here, but afaik I cant use an older version of the chromedriver since my chrome has updated itself to 78, is there a way to hardcore things so it runs as if the chrome version is earlier to match earlier builds of chromedriver?.

I'm not sure if the issue is with CD or protractor or selenium or what to be honest. I'm honestly at a loss at whats gone wrong.

Comment: try this https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7125792?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but unfortunately I dont have an msi for an earlier verison so I am unable to make this happen, I am instead pursuing firefox for now, if I ever figure out what caused this I'll be back hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to fix your chrome version to an earlier version when you are running your webdriver manager update. Use this line of code to see if it works.

```
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager clean
```

This will remove all previous versions of chrome already downloaded.

```
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone --versions.standalone=3.8.0 --chrome --versions.chrome=78.0.3904.97
```

This will downgrade your chrome and keep it downgraded next time you run your webdriver manager update so that the tests wont fail.

I hope this helps. :)